# Finding Key value from JSON Object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I hava a JSON Object in my javascript code that is like :

```
{"0" : "Jul 09, 2012 05:05 PM", "3" : "Jul 09, 2012 05:08 PM"}
```

I have decoded this JSON using

```
var jsonObj = eval('(' + {/literal}{$json}{literal} + ')');
```

I can access values using

```
jsonObj[i]
```

but this gives me an error if i access jsonObj[2] since it is not in my json.

So i wish to have a way to access first part of JSON i.e. the key part. so that i store them in an array in JS and loop through them.

Comment: do you want to use jQuery framework? $.parseJSON (json).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

eval is evil. Anyway, if you want to loop through the properties ('keys') of your json, you can do

```
for(key in jsonObj) {
   if(jsonObj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
     //do something with the values
     // jsonObj[key] 
   }
}
```

Comment: why is that evil ? Also your thing worked for me. Thanks Vishal

Comment: @user1290495: It's "evil" because the `eval` method will execute *anything* that's in the string, so if it contained script, that would run. A JSON parser on the other hand will only accept a string that actually contains only JSON.

Comment: Exactly what guffa said. Also, the additional requirement is the fact that the 'json string' is expected to be near perfect and will cause problems if there are even small mistakes. So its always better to use an external library like jquery to do this for you (jQuery.parseJSON)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (jsonObj.hasOwnProperty('2')) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modern browsers have the "static" method Object.keys(). There is a shim for older browsers. Then you can loop over the returned array of keys, or use .indexOf() or .inArray() if you are using most frameworks.